# Mouse click on an icon on screen using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to execute a mouse click on the 'cross icon' in the picture below.

[Image here](https://i.ibb.co/TLGV0RJ/cross.jpg)

The cross icon has the following identifiers:

1. Inner HTML = `<span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-clear">×</span>`
2. Outer HTML = `<span class="ng-clear-wrapper" title="Clear all"><span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-clear">×</span></span>`
3. CSS Selector = `tr.parameter-data:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > ng-select:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)`

However when I execute the Javascript code , there is no clicks happening, please guide.

> document.querySelector('[class="ng-clear"]').click()

Comment: Voting to close as this question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**tryout this one**

```
 document.querySelector('.ng-clear').click()
```

Comment: This isnt working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As you appear to have multiple span elements that need to receive the `click` event, use `querySelectorAll` and assign a listener to each or use a `delegated event listener` as here and use the className to identify elements of interest prior to dispatching the `click` event. To test this, try with the `click()` and without to observe the number of console entries

```js
document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  if( e.target.classList.contains('ng-clear') ){
    e.target.click();
    console.info(e.type)
  }
})
```

```css
.ng-clear{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px dotted grey;
  border-radius:0.5rem;
  padding:1rem;
  margin:0 1rem;
  font-size:2rem;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-clear">×</span>

<span class="ng-clear-wrapper" title="Clear all">
  <span aria-hidden="true" class="ng-clear">×</span>
</span>
```